# How to avoid repeating yourself in WSDL operations with identical SOAP headers

Tags: soap, wsdl

I am working on a WSDL file that defines a number of  elements. Something like this:

```
<wsdl:operation name="MyOperationName">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.domain.dk/myschema#MyService" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input name="MyServiceRequest">
            <soap:header use="literal" part="SecurityHeader" message="tns:SecurityHeader"/>
            <soap:header use="literal" part="SomethingElseHeader" message="tns:SomethingElseHeader"/>
            <soap:header use="literal" part="WhitelistingHeader" message="tns:WhitelistingHeader" wsdl:required="true"/>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="MyServiceResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    <wsdl:fault name="MyFault">
        <soap:fault name="MyFault" use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I have a lot of wsdl operations and they all share the same identical list of soap:header elements:

```
            <soap:header use="literal" part="SecurityHeader" message="tns:SecurityHeader"/>
            <soap:header use="literal" part="SomethingElseHeader" message="tns:SomethingElseHeader"/>
            <soap:header use="literal" part="WhitelistingHeader" message="tns:WhitelistingHeader" wsdl:required="true"/>
```

Is there some way to define this just once and then somehow "add" it to the wsdl operations as some sort of reference? This way I would only have to change something one place if the headers were to change or of I needed to add a new header.

I've been trying to extend the wsdl:input element like this (see below) but I'm waay out of my depth here xml/wsdl wise. But this illustrates what I am looking for.

```
<xs:complexType name="StandardHeaders">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="wsdl:operation">
            <soap:header use="literal" part="SecurityHeader" message="tns:SecurityHeader"/>
            <soap:header use="literal" part="SomethingElseHeader" message="tns:SomethingElseHeader"/>
            <soap:header use="literal" part="WhitelistingHeader" message="tns:WhitelistingHeader" wsdl:required="true"/>
        </xs:extension>xx
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
...
<wsdl:input name="MyServiceRequest">
    <tns:StandardHeaders />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've been digging into this problem and have found a solution that works for me. There are other ways to do this that might work for others, such as parsing other things than WSDL with Axis2 or being able to perform some XSLT preprocessing, but what worked for me was XML ENTITY definitions. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE definitions [
<!ENTITY myStandardSOAPRequestHeaders "
            <soap:header use='literal' part='Header1Part' message='tns:header1' />
            <soap:header use='literal' part='Header2Part' message='tns:header2' />
">
<!ENTITY myStandardSOAPResponseHeaders "
            <soap:header use='literal' part='RespHeader1' message='tns:resp1'/>
            <soap:header use='literal' part='RespHeader2' message='tns:resp2'/>
">
]>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
....
&myStandardSOAPRequestHeaders;
```

So basically you include an ENTITY definition containing the XML you want to reuse, then reference that XML using &entityName;

In my case I used inline ENTITY definitions which are not so pretty to look at (having xml inside attribute values) but you can reference external files as well, like this:

```
<!ENTITY myHeader PUBLIC "path/to/external.xml">
```

There are a number of useful sites that discuss this. I found this one useful:

https://www.liquid-technologies.com/XML/EntityRefs.aspx

(I'm not affiliated with them just found them with Google)